# How do I create a color gradient toolbar that will allow the user to change the color of a Collada 3D Model?

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, webgl

Essentially, what I'm asking is: How do I create a color gradient toolbar that will allow the user to change the color of a Collada 3D Model? So that, when I select the object or structure, I can transition from a bright yellow to a creamier yellow to a pastel yellow to near orange like yellow nearly seamlessly.

The collada files imported from Blender are in meshPhongMaterial if that means anything.

Please let me know if there are any examples or tutorials I can follow or where I can begin. Thank you.

EDIT:

For example,

If I took this example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

and I wanted to add something like this color toolbar:  http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#4--Color-Controllers

How do I connect the 3D object with the color picker is essentially what I'm saying.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to create a JavaScript color picker? How to apply a color to a threejs material? If it's both, your question is too broad. And even if this is only about one topic, you have to be more specific, and show where should that fit into your existing code, and what you already tried.

Comment: I guess I was asking about soemthing like the tube color picker here: http://troilk.github.io/cs291-contest/ (Just found out about it). I'll look at the source code and ask a more specific question in a little bit. Sorry for the trouble but thanks :D

Comment: No trouble, I'm just trying to help

Comment: There's plenty of color pickers in jquery: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+color+picker